# Print or save tp csv a json file with unicode chars and extra fields

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x

I am being provided a JSON results file from some script with seems to have Unicode characters and some fields which are not necessary such as "Decimal".
I have no idea what was used to create the JSON report.

The JSON file has over 2000+ entries. The example below has only the first two entries for simplicity.

```
"{u'Count': 2119, u'Items': [{u'vlan': Decimal('2'), u'location': u'site1', u'vlan_name': u'vlan1'}, {u'vlan': Decimal('3'), u'location': u'site1', u'vlan_name': u'vlan3'}], u'ScannedCount': 2119, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': 'UOH8U2E4THOGDHJ5BKODNS4I83VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG', 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'UOH8U2E4THOGDHJ5BKODNS4I83VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG', 'content-length': '209370', 'server': 'Server', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amz-crc32': '2084548256', 'date': 'Thu, 13 Aug 2020 18:14:21 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0'}}}"
```

Looking to print or save to csv as:

```
vlan    location    vlan_name
2       site1       vlan1
3       site2       vlan3
```

But no matter what I do, can't get it correct.

Below is the code but only the first data set works, which I created manually.

```
Data set 1: Created manually
Data set 2: Original with only two entries provided
Data set 3: Original removing "u'"
Data set 4: Same as #1 but with "Decimal" added



#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7

import json
import csv

vlan_data = '{"Items":[{"vlan": "11", "location": "site_1", "vlan_name": "vlan_name_11"},{"vlan": "12", "location": "site_1", "vlan_name": "vlan_name_12"}]}'
#vlan_data = "{u'Count': 2119, u'Items': [{u'vlan': Decimal('11'), u'location': u'site_1', u'vlan_name': u'vlan_name_11'}, {u'vlan': Decimal('12'), u'location': u'site_1', u'vlan_name': u'vlan_name_2'}], u'ScannedCount': 2119, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': 'UOH8U2E4THOGDHJ5BKODNS4I83VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG', 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'UOH8U2E4THOGDHJ5BKODNS4I83VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG', 'content-length': '209370', 'server': 'Server', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amz-crc32': '2084548256', 'date': 'Thu, 13 Aug 2020 18:14:21 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0'}}}"
#vlan_data = "{Count': 2119, Items': [{vlan': Decimal('11'), location': site_1', vlan_name': vlan_name_11'}, {vlan': Decimal('12'), location': site_1', vlan_name': vlan_name_12'}], ScannedCount': 2119, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': 'UOH8U2E4THOGDHJ5BKODNS4I83VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG', 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'UOH8U2E4THOGDHJ5BKODNS4I83VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG', 'content-length': '209370', 'server': 'Server', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amz-crc32': '2084548256', 'date': 'Thu, 13 Aug 2020 18:14:21 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0'}}}"
#vlan_data = '{"Items":[{"vlan": Decimal("11"), "location": "site_1", "vlan_name": "vlan_name_11"},{"vlan": Decimal("12"), "location": "site_1", "vlan_name": "vlan_name_12"}]}'
        
vlan_parsed = json.loads(vlan_data)

emp_data = vlan_parsed['Items']

# open a file for writing

v1_data = open('/Users/sergiogomez/Downloads/Vlan_Data.csv', 'w')

# create the csv writer object

csvwriter = csv.writer(v1_data)

count = 0

for v1 in emp_data:

      if count == 0:

             header = v1.keys()

             csvwriter.writerow(header)

             count += 1

      csvwriter.writerow(v1.values())

v1_data.close()
```

Error for the 3 commented data lines is for line:

vlan_parsed = json.loads(vlan_data)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/**init**.py", line 348, in loads

```
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
```

Any suggestions/tips?

Comment: But what exactly is the problem?  Is an exception raised? Or is it that your output is not what's expected?

Comment: @qouify, sorry, forgot to add that, the original post has been edited.
But beginning to think the file provided is not a valid format

Comment: That's also my opinion.  I would say that `Decimal('11')` is not valid json.